# testing uniqueness scope validation using shoulda matchers

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, unique, shoulda

I have a model as

```
class ObjectiveConcept < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :objective_id, presence: true
  validates :concept_id, presence: true
  validates :concept_id, uniqueness: {scope: :objective_id}

  belongs_to :objective
  belongs_to :concept
end
```

and the model validations using shoulda matchers is as

```
require 'spec_helper'                                                                                                                                   

describe ObjectConcept do

 describe "#Validations" do
   it{ should validate_presence_of(:objective_id) }

   it{ should validate_presence_of(:concept_id) }

   it 'should validate uniqueness of concept_id scoped to object_id' do
     objective = FactoryGirl.create(:objective, name: 'some objective')

     concept = FactoryGirl.create(:concept, name: 'some concept')

     subject { FactoryGirl.create(:object_concept, concept_id: concept.id, objective_id: objective.id) }
     should validate_uniqueness_of(:concept_id).scoped_to(:objective_id)
    end
  end

  describe "#Associations" do
    it{ should belong_to(:objective) }
    it{ should belong_to(:concept) }
  end
end
```

When i run the spec for uniqueness, i get the below error

```
 ObjectiveConcept#Validations should validate uniqueness of concept_id scoped to objective_id
 Failure/Error: should validate_uniqueness_of(:concept_id).scoped_to(:objective_id)
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "objective_id" violates not-null constraint
   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (20, null, 0, 2014-09-09 10:24:36.87583, 2014-09-09 10:24:36.87583).
   : INSERT INTO "objective_concepts" ("concept_id", "created_at", "objective_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"
```

I have populated the subject for the uniqueness validation as specified under the 'Caveat' section at http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/Shoulda/Matchers/ActiveModel#validate_uniqueness_of-instance_method but to no effect. How do i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by removing the code out of the subject block.

replaced

```
subject { FactoryGirl.create(:object_concept, concept_id: concept.id, objective_id: objective.id) }
```

with

```
FactoryGirl.create(:object_concept, concept_id: concept.id, objective_id: objective.id)
```